# Python: Multiple Filters of Grouped Data

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to filter out the list below to show only the line items that have the same Supplier, same Quality (can be an infinite amount of ratings), but different Type (would only be two different values).

For example, I could use Supplier ABC A rated wood or steel but would not be able to do the same switch with Supplier DEF (given wood and steel have different Quality). The desired output would be a table only showing ABC's A rated steel and wood and GHI's B rated steel and wood.

I figured out how to only show supplies that offer both wood and steel (i.e. eliminates JKL) but cannot figure out how to further filter to show suppliers with different Type but equal Quality.

```
df.groupby('Supplier').filter(lambda x:x['Type'].nunique()>1)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Input Data:

```
  Supplier Quality   Type
0      ABC       A   Wood
1      ABC       B  Steel
2      ABC       A  Steel
3      DEF       B  Steel
4      DEF       A   Wood
5      GHI       C   Wood
6      GHI       A   Wood
7      GHI       A  Steel
8      JKL       A   Wood
9      JKL       A   Wood
```

Comment: please copy and paste your df in the question; do not use images.

Comment: Sorry about that, just updated

Comment: I guess you meant you need GHI's A rated wood and steel, not B rated - did't you?

Comment: Yes, I must have pasted the wrong version. I changed those to B rated to show there can be multiple ratings for each type (I.e. not just A rated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just group by on both Supplier and Quality:

```
df.groupby(['Supplier', 'Quality']).filter(lambda x: x['Type'].nunique() > 1)

  Supplier Quality   Type
0      ABC       A   Wood
2      ABC       A  Steel
6      GHI       A   Wood
7      GHI       A  Steel
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help, this worked perfectly. I have been banging my head against a wall for weeks trying to figure this out so you certainly saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 0):

based on what you have tried you are looking for unique types grater than 1 so you can do something like this:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['Supplier', 'Quality'])['Type'].unique().to_frame()
df2[df2['Type'].str.len() >1]


                       Type
Supplier    Quality 
ABC            A    [Wood, Steel]
GHI            A    [Wood, Steel]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `drop_duplicates` and `duplicated` with `keep=False`:

```
key_cols = ['Supplier', 'Quality']

res = df.drop_duplicates().loc[:, key_cols]

res = res.loc[res.duplicated(keep=False)]\
         .drop_duplicates()

print(res)

  Supplier Quality
0      ABC       A
6      GHI       A
```